# Using JMockIt, Unable to Deencapsulate the private constructor of an enum singleton

Tags: jacoco, jmockit

I have an enum singleton with private constructor; while I could get all my methods unit tested and covered by Jacoco but Jacoco coverage seemed low mainly because of the private constructor I believe; To get the better numbers, I have decided to give a go to Deencapsulate the private constructor and create the instance but JMocKIt complains that it cannot find the compatible constructor.

```
public enum Adapter implements HimTranscriptionFrameworkAdapter {
    /** Singleton Instance. */
    INSTANCE;

    /**
     * Initializes the Adapter.
     */
    private Adapter() {
        isStarted = false;
    }
    public void startup() throws Exception {}
}
```

and I have this in my test:

```
Adapter deencapsulatedAdapter =
            Deencapsulation.newInstance(Adapter.class);
        deencapsulatedAdapter.startup();
```

and I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible constructor found:
>   Adapter()

I would to seek your help in this regard.

Comment: Correct if I am wrong here, but wouldn't Adapter.INSTANCE give the required JaCoCo coverage, unless the enums are initialized outside the JaCoCo's instrumentation scope (not sure how that can happen).

Comment: that's right but is it not possible to Deencapsulate the private constructor of an enum class?

Comment: That might be a  question for JMockit authors. Have you tried reaching out them?

Comment: This is response I received from JMockIt:No enum can be instantiated through Reflection, regardless of its constructors. JMockit doesn't have a Deencapsulation.newInstance method anymore